# Lattice paths with step length different from 1

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Starting at $(x, y)$, how many different ways you can go to $(w, z)$, with steps $(a, b)$ or $(c, d)$, assuming you always go forward either in right or up direction (i.e. $a, c > 0$ or $b, d > 0$)?

Original problem: Start at $(0, 0)$, go to $(9n, n)$ with steps $(2, 3)$ or $(1, -2)$. You can go above n or below 0, so e.g. $(<whatever>, 2n)$ is a valid point to be in. However I'd like to know a generalization of this problem, so my actual question refers to 1st paragraph. Please let me know if I skipped any possible assumption in my generalization attempt.

A simple link will do, because I struggle to find anything that's not NE lattice path.

Answer (score 0):

Without loss of generality, let's assume that $a,c>0$. We need to check if the equation
$$
\left(\begin{matrix}
a&c\\
b&d\\
\end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}
m\\
n\\
\end{matrix}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix}
w-x\\
z-y\\
\end{matrix}\right)
$$
has a solution, $m,n\geq 0$. Then since we need $m$ steps of $(a,b)$ and $n$ steps of $(c,d)$, there are ${m+n \choose n}$ possible paths.